# defining powershell function for python -m

Tags: powershell, python

I am trying to do something I thought would be trivial.
I just wanted to declare a function as that

```
function mds {
python -m "blabla" $args
}
```

but it's just not working under Powershell.
I got this error:

```
mds : The term 'python -m os:String' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Ch
eck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

As I understand Powershell takes the whole `python -m "asdfadsf"` as command, but why? And how can I workaround it ?

Comment: meterr - Simply try `Start-Process python "-m blabla $args" -Wait` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell has no idea what that python code is, hence the error.
Also, there are several reserved words, variables (automatic and default). Point of note ...

```
$args
```

... is one of those, so, not one you can use in your code for your own use.

> $args Automatic Variable in PowerShell ‘$args’ is an Automatic
>   variable in PowerShell that contains an array of the undeclared
>   parameters passed to a script

```
# iterating through the arguments
# and performing an operation on each
$args | ForEach-Object { $_*2 }
"Argument count: $($args.Count)"
"First Argument : $($args[0])"
"Second Argument : $($args[1])"
"Last Argument : $($args[-1])"
$args.GetType() # get the type of the object
```

Also, python notwithstanding, this is not the way to call external commands in PowerShell. There are well-documented resources regarding how to call external commands from PowerShell scripts/functions. For example:

> [PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)
>
> [Solve Problems with External Command Lines in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/solve-problems-with-external-command-lines-in-powershell)
>
> [Top 5 tips for running external commands in Powershell](https://powershelleverydayfaq.blogspot.com/2012/04/top-5-tips-for-running-external.html)
>
> [Execution of External Commands in PowerShell Done Right](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/execution-of-external-commands-in-powershell-done-right)
>
> [Using Windows PowerShell to run old command-line tools (and their
>   weirdest parameters)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters)
>
> See also about Redirection
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220933/powershell-pipe-external-command-output-to-another-external-command
>
> Quoting specifics
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules
>   https://trevorsullivan.net/2016/07/20/powershell-quoting

Lastly...

> [PowerShell Scripting Guide to Python – Passing Command-Line
>   Arguments](https://ridicurious.com/2018/08/28/powershell-scripting-guide-to-python-passing-command-line-arguments)
>
> [About Automatic Variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6)

All in all, you'd end up with something like this...

```
$PythonArgs = @('-m', 
'pip',
'install', 
'--upgrade'
'pip')

function mds {
    & 'python.exe' $PythonArgs
}

mds

# Results
<#
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in d:\scripts\python\pycharmprojects\test\venv\lib\site-packages (19.3.1)
#>
```